# IIS binding prefixes localhost

Tags: c#, iis

Is there a way to set up a binding in iis in the format of:

website1.localhost:80

website2.localhost:80

website3.lcoalhost:80

etc

I set the websites up to use different ports but there is a resource that is needed which is hosted on port 80 on the same server. The other websites are now looking for this resource, assuming it runs on the same port as them (example :8001, :8002, :8003)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your IIS Manager, go to `Edit Bindings...` of your website and add a site binding with `website1.localhost` as host name on the port 80.
Next, edit the file `c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` to append an entry:

```
127.0.0.1       website1.localhost
```

Repeat the same above steps with other websites and you can navigate to http://website1.localhost/, http://website2.localhost/...

Comment: This works, but lets now say I want to access these websites from another PC on the same network or domain using these bindings? I am accepting this answer in the meantime as my original question did not explain my end goal properly.

Comment: @ElmarleGrange, if `website1.localhost` being accessed from another PC then the `host` file on that PC should have mapping: `[web host IP]     website1.localhost`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: @BobDust Do you know by chance, if this should also work for IIS net named pipe binding? This would solve my problem described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73162436/wcf-netnamedpipebinding-with-sub-path-and-security. I've given it a try, but no luck so far.

Comment: @MatthiasMüller, named pipe is the binding for inter-process communication on the same machine so of course its usage is all about local host. To resolve the collision between your wcf service and iis website, I think binding a different port might help. And you may consider remove security setting for wcf named pipe binding.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling for a week on this. My application is an ASP.NET MVC application. I tried disabling the firewall, enabling TSL12, and other things.

This was the solution!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31618249)